# In styler package of tidyverse, style_text prompts user input when first run

Tags: r, tidyverse

```r
> packageVersion('styler')
[1] ‘1.3.2’
```

```r
> style_text("A <- 1")
The R.cache package needs to create a directory that will hold cache files. It is convenient to use  ‘C:\Users\A0765618\AppData\Local\R\R.cache’ because it follows the standard on your operating system and it remains also after restarting R. Do you wish to create the 'C:\Users\A0765618\AppData\Local\R\R.cache' directory? If not, a temporary directory (C:\Users\A0765618\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6z4Eit/.Rcache) that is specific to this R session will be used. [Y/n]:
```

How can I run this functionally initially without this prompt? Can I set the answer to the prompt prior to calling? For example, how can I set it to `n` so that no prompt is needed?

This function will be called in a shiny app, so this prompt, which appears in the console will cause a bug.

Comment: Would an early call to `R.cache::setCacheRootPath()` solve the problem?

Comment: @Limey running that function only prompts the user with the same message. it does not the prompt go away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR;**

put this before you call `{styler}` where the directory should already exist:

```r
options(R.cache.rootPath = '/path/to/your/cache/dir')
```

---

You have the following options:

**Deactivate the cache altogether**

First of all, you can get rid of the caching problem by deactivating it altogether with `styler::cache_deactivate()`. Then, the prompt should not show up. To make this permanent, put this line in your `.Rprofile`.

**Setting up the cache programmatically**

However, if you want to benefit from the speed up the cache brings in your setting, you can set it up programmatically. I am [just updating the docs](https://github.com/r-lib/styler/pull/717) for it (if you have comments please let me know):

> In some cases, you want to avoid the interactive prompt described above. In that situation, you can set the path to the cache with the R option `R.cache.rootPath` or the environment variable `R_CACHE_ROOTPATH` to an existent path before you call the `{styler}` API. This should avoid the prompt. `R.cache::setCacheRootPath("/path/to/cache")` is also programmatic but will probably give the prompt anyways if called interactively.

So just do `options(R.cache.rootPath = '/path/to/your/cache/dir')`.

You can also silence the pretty color warning (if you don't want to install it) with setting the option `styler.colored_print.vertical` as described in `help(print.vertical, package = 'styler')`.

In addition, there is a `styler.quiet` option in `styler > 1.3.2` but it likely won't have any impact because what you are seeing is directly coming from `{R.cache}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
R.cache::setCacheRootPath(getwd())
```

Does indeed produce an undesirable message and prompt:

```
The R.cache package needs to create a directory that will hold cache files. It is
convenient to use  '<xxxx>/Caches/R/R.cache' because it follows the standard on your
operating system and it remains also after restarting R. Do you wish to create the
'<xxxx>/Caches/R/R.cache' directory? If not, a temporary directory (/var/folder
/47/4_fn5xyx01b8_8bnyn8cpv3c0000gn/T//RtmpdO3NGa/.Rcache) that is specific to this
R session will be used. [Y/n]:
```

But, taking the hint in the prompt,

```
R.cache::setCacheRootPath("<xxxx>/Caches/R/R.cache")
```

runs without error or warning.

Then, after installing the `prettycode` package,

```
style_text("A <- 1")
```

produces

```
A <- 1
```

without message or warning.

Is it worth dropping a note to tidyverse asking for a `styler.silent` option?